# Creating Facebook Ads programmatically with Ads API or Atlas API

Tags: facebook, ads, facebook-ads-api

Which API we can use for Facebook Ad creation programmatically in C#?Atlas API or ADs API. I have gone through both API documents and I find that both object names are different and Ads API is very similar to Facebook Ad fields. But I couldn't find any code samples for Ads API where as we have the code samples for Atlas API but object names are different compared to Facebook Ad. Please suggest me which API is better to use and what the process to access both Ads API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create ads on Facebook, you'll want to use the Facebook Ads API.  This API is JSON based and pretty much any Graph API client library should be able to connect to it.  One caveat is you'll need to request access to the Ads API, which might take a bit of time to get reviewed and enabled.  The documentation for this API is here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ads-api/

The Atlas API is primarily used to serve display ads and measure their performance.  It doesn't sound like that's your primary use case here.

Answer (score 0):

There are no C# Ads SDK that I am aware, but you can start with a C# Facebook SDK that will help you with lower level objects such as requests, accesstokens, batch requests etc.
http://facebooksdk.net/

And to build your Business Logic Layer, here is the spec: 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ads-api/